# How to center div inside div in following case

Tags: html, css

i got problem with setting my layout right, elemnts doesn't align way i want to and i'm running out of ideas, or repeat same misteakes.

There is wrapper(green) thats fits its size to page width, container that i want to center (blue) that shrinks or expands depending on page width and then rectangular elements(brown) that i want to center inside container (blue) and allow them to rearrange according to width of container (size and amount is not constant)

HTML

```
<div id="tiles_wrap">
    <div id="tiles">
        <div class="tilewrap">
            <div class="tilebg">
                <div class="ribbon">aaab</div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="tilewrap">
            <div class="tilebg">
                <div class="ribbon">aaav</div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="tilewrap">
            <div class="tilebg">
                <div class="ribbon">aaaa</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tilewrap">
            <div class="tilebg">
                <div class="ribbon">bbbv</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tiles_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
    float: left;
    padding-left:25%;
    padding-right:25%;
}
#tiles {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    float: center;
    Padding: 40px;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}
.tilewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.tilebg {
    height: 55px;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: brown;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
.ribbon {
    color: #fff;
    padding:2px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    z-ndex: 22;
}
```

Thanks in advance fr all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `float` for this, there is no `float: center;` so that's one of your problems. Also, absolutely positioning elements tends to fix them to a particular spot, so they're not very good for centering and re-arranging depending on width of container.

You can, however, use `display: inline-block;` along with `text-align: center;` to do what you're after.

Also, don't forget that if you set the width of an object to `100%`, then add `25%` padding on the left and right sides, you are making the total width of that object `150%` of its parent (in the normal `content-box` model.)

http://jsfiddle.net/UQ34L/1/

Answer (score 0):

To get the blue to center, you need to set a width for #tiles, then remove the padding from #tiles_wrap.  There is no such thing as float:center, so that is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#tiles_wrap {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
            float: left;
}

#tiles {
       width: 65%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       Padding: 40px;
       font-size: 12px;
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRcY/)

As suggested by others, I've added display: inline-block to get the divs to sit alongside each other.  As well as this, I added a wrapper div with id="wrapper" and applied a text-align: center to have the tiles align in the center.

Also I added a div with id="tiles_left" for the left margin div with a width of 30% and removed your "tiles_wrap" div as it is not needed with the changes I made.  The "tiles" div with a width of 70%

```
<div id="tiles_left">
    hello
</div>
<div id="tiles">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="tilewrap">
    <div class="tilebg">
        <div class="ribbon">aaab</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="tilewrap">
    <div class="tilebg">
        <div class="ribbon">aaav</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="tilewrap">
    <div class="tilebg">
        <div class="ribbon">aaaa</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tilewrap">
    <div class="tilebg">
        <div class="ribbon">bbbv</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```